# Is it possible to append inline quotation marks to a blockquote that contains multiple paragraphs using <p> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, twig

I have a `blockquote` that contains multiple `<p>` tags and I'm trying to surround the entire text with quotation marks. I need these quotation marks to be automatically appended directly beside the text (inline) and I also need the `<p>` elements to appear as separate paragraphs and to **not** be concatenated into one single text block.

NOTE: **the marked possible duplicate is NOT**. This is a stylistic approach. I need the quotes to appear as content within the `blockquote`.

This is a seemingly simplistic issue that has stumped me.

**What I've tried:**

Display inline for the initial `<p>`  tag.

Position the opening quotation manually.

Display both `<p>` tags inline (which would solve the issue) because they would then go inline with each other, creating a giant block of text.

I could inject a break after the opening `<p>` tag using javascript, but that would not be ideal. I'm guessing I could also concatenate the quotation marks using js, but I haven't tested this and I would prefer not to use JS at all.

**Example output**

```
<blockquote>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some other text</p>
</blockquote>
```

**What I need**

> "This was a great day because it's sunny out.
>
> Let me tell you why the sun is awesome"

**What I get**

> "
>
> This was a great day because it's sunny out.
>
> Let me tell you why the sun is awesome
>
> "

Comment: *Not a duplicate, that is an entirely different question*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some CSS that I think gets what you're looking for:

```css
blockquote>p:first-child:before {
  content: "\"";
}

blockquote>p:last-child:after {
  content: "\"";
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some other text</p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: I'm dumbfounded that I wasn't able to think of this. I spent the entire time trying to modify the blockquote element with pseudo classes. I will make a minor change to your answer to protect against blockquotes that don't open and close with <p> tags. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with `display: table-row` / `display: table-cell`

```css
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  display: table-cell;
  content: "\0022";
  font-size: 4rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: '\201C';
}

blockquote:after {
  content: '\201D';
}

blockquote {
  display: table-row;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>You know you’re in love when you can’t fall asleep because reality is finally better than your dreams.</p>
  <p>Bottom text</p>
</blockquote>
```

---

Or with `display: grid`

```css
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after {
  font-size: 6rem;
  grid-row: 1;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: '\201C';
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

blockquote:after {
  content: '\201D';
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}

blockquote {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>You know you’re in love when you can’t fall asleep because reality is finally better than your dreams.</p>
  <p>Bottom text</p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: This is a stylistic approach. I need the quotes to appear as content within the blockquote.

Comment: If these were the answer, then the linked possible duplicate would be a similar and these examples should be there and this marked as a duplicate. Instead (it's not a duplicate) therefore this is not the right answer here either way.